# Changing text variable from another imported script

Tags: python, checkbox, tkinter

So we have two scripts the first being AdidasStock.py and the second being StockWindow.py. I am trying to replace the base url in **getVarientStock** from **StockWindow.py**. Once again my apology's I am really new to python.

I am getting an error :

> aulocale1() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)

```
class AdidasStock:

    def __init__(self, clientId, sku):

        self.session = requests.session()
        self.headers = {"User-Agent" : "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/38.0.2125.111 Safari/537.36",
                        "Accept-Language" : "REPLACETHISPLIZZZ"}
        self.locale = ''
        self.clientId = clientId
        self.sku = sku
        self.skus = []

    def getVarientStock(self, sku, base):
        base = "http://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-AU-Site/en_AU"
        urlVariantStock = base + '/Product-GetVariants?pid=' + sku
        r = requests.get(urlVariantStock, headers=self.headers)
```

Here is how I am trying to change the above base , self.locale, and a portion of self.headers. I am using a Tkinter Checkbutton to trigger this function.

**Checkbutton**

```
aulocale = IntVar()
aucheck = Checkbutton(self.master, variable=aulocale, onvalue=1, offvalue=0, text="AU",command=self.aulocale1)
```

**This is the Function**

```
 def aulocale1(self,base):
        base.replace = "http://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-AU-Site/en_AU"
        self.locale.replace = ('','AU')
        self.headers.replace = ('REPLACETHISPLIZZZ','en-AU,en;q=0.8')

    def uklocale1(self,base):
        base.replace = "www.adidas.co.uk/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-GB-Site/en_GB"
        self.locale.replace = ('','GB')
        elf.headers.replace = ('REPLACETHISPLIZZZ','en-GB,en;q=0.8')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Function `def aulocale1(self,base):` expects one argument - `base` but when you assign this function to `Checkbox` using `command=self.aulocale1` then `Checkbox` will execute this function without arguments - it will run `self.aulocale1()`

You can assign to `command` function with arguments using `lambda`

```
command=lambda:self.aulocale1("argument")
```

(BTW: if you will use `lambda` in `for` loop then you will have other problems ;) )

---

`base` is local variable so you can't change it ... but you can run this function with argument `base` so you can use default value for this argument

```
def getVarientStock(self, sku, base="http://www.adidas.com.au/ ...")
    urlVariantStock = base + '/Product-GetVariants?pid=' + sku
    r = requests.get(urlVariantStock, headers=self.headers)
```

If you run it without `base`

```
getVarientStock("XX")
```

then it uses `"http://www.adidas.com.au/ ..."` as `base`

but if you run it with second argument

```
getVarientStock("XX", "http://stackoverflow.com")
```

then it uses `"http://stackoverflow.com"` as `base`

Comment: Can you please further explain :). When you say run getVarianetStock how am I running it from the checkbox?

Comment: I didn't say "run getVarianetStock from checkbox" - I only show how to run `getVarianetStock` with different `base`. BTW: you show only small part of code and I don't understand what you try to do - you use son "replace" which make no sense for me.

Comment: My apologises furas. I really appreciate your help! This thread might better explain what I was trying to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41655700/issues-with-changing-variable-using-checkbox

I was basicially trying to alter the base url from a different script using a tkinter checkbox. I have two or 3 alternate base urls that I need to use :).