# Issues with changing variable using checkbox

Tags: python, variables, checkbox, global-variables, local

I'm quite new to Python and was having some confusing issues. I have two scripts **main.py** and **second.py**. I have a base url that needs to be changed in the **second.py** see bellow example

```
def getVarientStock(self, sku,base="http://www.baseurl.com"):
    urlVariantStock = base + '/Product-GetVariants?pid=' + sku
    r = requests.get(urlVariantStock, headers=self.headers)
    try:
        versions = json.loads(r.text)['variations']['variants']
    except:
        if r.status_code == 404:
            return {'error' : '"' + self.sku + '" is an invalid SKU!'}
        else:
            return {'error' : 'There was an error checking Stock, make sure the SKU is correct and try again.'}
        return
```

Now in main.py I am trying to figure out how I can have multiple different checkboxes to assign different base url's. I beleive the issue I am having is because it is a local variable?? **second.py** is imported into **main.py**.

This is the checkbox

```
is_checked = IntVar()
        self.aucheck = Checkbutton(self.master, text='AU', onvalue=1, offvalue=0, variable=is_checked)
        self.aucheck.pack(in_=top, side=LEFT)
```

And this is the funciton that I'm trying to figure out

```
def callcheckbox(self,):  
    if(is_checked.get()):
       getVarientStock.base =("XX","http://www.adidas.com.au/on/demandware.store/Sites-adidas-AU-Site/en_AU")
```

Really appreciate the assistance!! Sorry if this is a silly question Im still learning

Comment: it seems you don't know basics of python - you don't  know how to execute function/method - `self.getVarientStock("xx", "http:...")`

Comment: if you have button then assign to button `Button(..., command=callcheckbox)`

Comment: or rather  with `self` - `command=self.callcheckbox`